# block the cart to a product without blocking the quantity

Tags: php, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, theme-customizer

I'm creating a course site where it is possible to register and pay via Woocomerce, I need to block the possibility of adding multiple courses (products) to the cart but leave the possibility to select the quantity.  I found several indications on how not to allow the insertion of multiple products in the cart including the quantity but not as I want.  therefore you should be able to choose only one product but with the desired quantity.